# How to differentiate stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) with multiple JSlider in the same class

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to write a program that has multiple JSliders in the same class, for JSliders to perform the actions I want it too, I need to define the actions inside stateChanged(ChangeEvent e), but how do I differentiate the actions of different sliders inside the same method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how do I differentiate the actions of different sliders inside the same method?

Same as for any similar Swing event -- get the source by calling `getSource()` on the XxxxEvent object, here I believe that it's a ChangeEvent, and with that source you can check which JSlider initiated the event.

Comment: Can you clarify how I would use getSource()? I'm new to java.

Comment: @Mike: better for you to first clarify your problem -- show your code so we can work with that. Otherwise all I'll be doing is regurgitating a tutorial that already exists and that you can find easily. Please note that you should always post pertinent code with your questions whenever possible.